# Looking for novel: group abducted by asteroid ship containing other alien abductees

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novel, spaceship

Looking for a novel I believe was published between 2010-2013. It had one, maybe two authors, one of which was also a screenwriter.

The book was about what appeared to be an asteroid approaching Earth. I think two missions were sent to the object, one from the US and one from India or China. Not all the astronauts survived, those that did discovered the object is a space ark. When the ark entered orbit, it abducted one or more groups of people from mission control sites and started to leave the solar system. The abductees found other abducted alien species aboard the ark, some friendly, others not so much. They also found that some of the astronauts had been resurrected by the ark.

The book ended without a real conclusion so I think the authors intended to write a sequel. Sound familiar to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're thinking of [Heaven's Shadow](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1937007642)

It's written by David S. Goyer and Michael Cassutt, both of whom are screenwriters; and the plot has to do with a mysterious alien ship arriving in the solar system, where it's met by two expeditions from Earth. The ship at first seems dead, but - unsurprisingly - this turns out not to be the case.

There's not one, but two sequels - Heaven's War and Heaven's Fall.